# How to get youku access_token

Tags: api, video, access-token, youku

Where can I find the `access_token`, `refresh_token` in my youku account?

I found out how to upload video to youku.com using external script with the use of a  API, but I need `access_token`, `refresh_token` to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to authorize your Youku app and to use the get code to obtain a token.

1. Go to `https://openapi.youku.com/v2/oauth2/authorize?client_id={YOURCLIENTID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={YOURCALLBACKURL}`.
2. Accept the authorization. You will be redirected to your callback URL. Be careful, it should be the same than the one you entered while creating your Youku application (same protocol too).
3. Use the get parameter code to get your access token by doing a POST CURL call to https://openapi.youku.com/v2/oauth2/token with the following parameters

   ```
   if(isset($_GET['code']))
   {
       $url    = "https://openapi.youku.com/v2/oauth2/token";
       $params = array(
           "client_id"     => $client_id,
           "client_secret" => $client_secret,
           "grant_type"    => 'authorization_code',
           "code"      => $_GET['code'],
           "redirect_uri"  => $callback_url
       );

       $str_params = http_build_query($params);
       $ch = curl_init();

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str_params);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       $result = curl_exec($ch);

       echo $result;
   }
   ```

The $result will be a json array containing the access_token `{"access_token":"3cc08bffcd48a86a0e540f9ed1be42f4","expires_in":"2592000","refresh_token":"f8d78ce2005c9d1e0b62cd29f61ba3f9","token_type":"bearer"}`

More infor here : http://open.youku.com/docs/docs?id=101

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Youku api here: http://open.youku.com/docs/tech_doc.html
It is in Chinese, so I suggest you open this link using google chrome, then right click the page (after it is finished loading) and press 'Translate to English'

Hope this helps