# youku search JS API in english

Tags: javascript, jsapi, youku

I need the youku (China youtube) API in English or an explanation how to use it.
This is the code from youtube I want to write with youku:

```
url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search',
data: {
       'part': 'snippet',
       'q': this.searchBox.val(),
       'type': 'video',
       'key': '***key***'
       },
```

Thank you!

Edit:
This topic was for everyone who wants to work with youku API.
I edited my question and I provided the correct answer.
You have to work with translator (no English version) and this is the correct path:
http://doc.open.youku.com/?docid=318

Please ready the Developer agreement as well:
http://doc.open.youku.com/?docid=312

Good luck.

Comment: I believe this is being downvoted because you tagged youtube-api, but this question is not specifically about that topic. You should use related tags. That being said, it was not difficult to spend a few moments of my time to help you. Please let me know if you need more assistance. :o)

Comment: Why to downvoted? I add an youtube api example. lame..

Comment: I agree.  Lame.  :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: I found the correct link, and you can use the browser to translate to english.  http://doc.open.youku.com/

The closest thing I can find to help you out this [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415774/how-to-get-youku-access-token), which contains a link that appears to go to Youku API documentation. I cannot get that link to open however. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. If you believe my answer is the correct one, please mark it as the correct answer. :-)