# How to authorize my application with Youku to upload videos to end user's account?

Tags: upload, youku

I am working on desktop video editing application. In this app I need to implement Youku video uploading feature. For this purpose I registered my app on https://cloud.youku.com and got the ClientId to use the Video Upload API.

The [official documentation](https://cloud.youku.com/docs?id=100) (Chinese) says that I need access and refresh tokens to use the Upload API. Using the Upload API with manually generated access token I managed to upload videos to **my own Youku** account.

However, in my application I need to upload videos to an end user's account. According to the answer on [How to get youku access_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415774/how-to-get-youku-access-token) I am trying to open the following URL to authorize my app in the end user's account.
`https://openapi.youku.com/v2/oauth2/authorize?state=&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fispringsolutions.com&response_type=code&client_id={MYAPPCLIENTID}`.

However I am getting the following error response:

> code=1005&type=SystemException&description=Client+id+invalid

I am using the same ClientId that I used to upload videos to my account.

I also found the following document http://api.sandbox.yes.youku.com/open_upload.html (Chinese, can be Google-translated) mentioning the different authorization URL `https://api.youku.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={CALLBACK_URL}&state=`. However this API is seems to be crossed out since September, 2015.

So, is it possible today to authorize a custom application in end user's account on Youku for video uploading? I have two hypotheses:

- Youku have removed the ability to authorize third party applications to upload videos to an end user's account

or

- The third party application have to pass a sort of verification process to get authorized in end user's account

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got a response from Youku on this question.

> hello 你好，
> 先解答您的问题
>
> 1.https://openapi.youku.com/v2/oauth2/authorize?这个接口已经废弃了，建议使用此文档中的上传方案https://cloud.youku.com/docs?id=109
>
> 2.您可以使用一个accesstoken，将您平台的视频统一上传至优酷同一个账号中，方便您管理内容
> 谢谢

Which is translated by Google as:

---

hello,
Answer your question first

1. https://openapi.youku.com/v2/oauth2/authorize? This interface has been deprecated, it is recommended to use the upload scheme in this document https://cloud.youku.com/docs?id=109
2. You can use one accesstoken to upload videos of your platform to the same account on Youku, which is convenient for you to manage content

Thank you

---

So, I can conclude that it is currently not possible to authorize your application with Youku to upload a video to another user account.

Youku Upload API is now suitable only for batch upload of videos to your account. You can't use the Youku Upload API in your application to let the application automatically upload a video to an end-user account. Users have to upload their videos manually to Youku via Web Browser.